# I cannot find Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices Reference in SSIS ScriptTask

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ssis

I have been given a copy of a production DTSX package that needs amending. I have moved this into my development pc. The DTXS package contains a ScriptTask object only. In this ScriptTask there are References to Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll and Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Auth.dll both of which have yellow exclamation marks:
[image]

I have found the DLLs online and installed them:
[image]

When I search for them in References they are still not listed:
[image]

When I use the Browse option and search for the folder it returns no items:
[image]

I tried to register the DLLs and got a message saying they didn't need registering.

Can someone please help.

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the wrong version of the Exchange Web Services DLL. I following the following link and fixed the issue:

https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/01/an-error-occurred-while-trying-to-load-a-required-component-please-ensure-that-the-following-prerequisite-component-is-installed-microsoft-exchange-webservices/

Cheers 
Rob